# How to mock an object with a function that has a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have this simple method that i'm trying to test.

```
function isS3Healthy(s3, logger = console) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.listObjects({}, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err)
        return resolve(['s3', false])
      }
      return resolve(['s3', true])
    })
  })
}
```

My test keeps timing out and it has to do with my mocked object isn't right. What does this mock object need to look like in order to test my method properly?

```
describe.only('#isS3Healthy', () => {
  let s3
  before(() => {
    s3 = {
      listObjects: ({}, (err, data) => {
        return Promise.resolve(['s3', true])
      })
    }
  })

  it('should return that it is healthy', () => {
    return isS3Healthy(s3)
      .then(result => {
        const [name, status] = result
        expect(name).to.equal('s3')
        expect(status).to.be.true
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err = ', err)
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to reject the promise when an error occurs? I would strongly recommend that if you're unsure `if (err) return reject(err)`

Comment: Also it is not directly related to your question but the aws-sdk S3 api has promise versions of these functions if it helps you to know. Try `s3.listObjects({}).promise()`

Comment: I'm certain i don't want to reject the error in this particular case. I didn't know about the `s3.toPromise()`! I'll try that first. I'm used to mocking promises. Been a long time since i've had to mock callbacks and i'm drawing a blank on this.

Comment: Sorry, its actually just `.promise()` here's the docs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided, it looks like `listObjects` is a function that accepts an object and a callback, and at some point calls that callback, so probably the simplest way to mock it would be like this:

```
listObjects: (_, c) => c()
```

The function you're testing only seems to care whether `listObjects` is passing an error to the callback or not, so this should seemingly be sufficient.

*Side note:* you have `return resolve` in two places in your `isS3Healthy` function, but using `return` here almost certainly serves no purpose. To resolve a promise, just call `resolve(...)` without returning it.

Comment: I purposely have resolve in 2 places as i'm returning a different boolean value. This was done on purpose for my calling promise chain that calls this method. I also always `return` my `resolve` b/c i've been bitten by code that resolves and then tries to continue to run other code since it doesn't return from the function.

Comment: @Catfish Yeah, having more than one `resolve` is normal, but I was referring to the use of `return resolve` in multiple places, since having that in even one place is weird for me. I now understand why you're doing that, but it would stick out as a code smell to me. If it were me and I wanted to end the function early, I would use `resolve(...); return;`. It's one extra line, but I think it conveys the intent more clearly. Different strokes for different folks, I guess.